# WordPress core update fails - no issues with plugin updates

Tags: plugins, themes, core, automatic-updates

My WP installation does one-click plugin / theme updates without any hiccups, but updates to the core always fails. No specific reason is cited, except for a suggestion that it may be due to file system permissions. It's hosted on a linux VPS.

What could possibly cause this? What kind of file / folder permissions are specifically required for core update? I'm not on shared hosting - so am free to modify the permissions as required.

Thank you,
m^e

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check what the Codex recommends for file permissions vs. what you are using.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a plugin. Try deactivating all plugins by using the plugin screen select all and use the bulk action to disable all.

Afterwhich try installing the WP update again and it should work assuming that this was wotking before and it recently stopped.